# Html5 video src redirect and get eror

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

I have got a video resource address, let's call it A, and set it as the src of `video` element. `A` shows up in `video` using element inspect, and another address `B` shows in network inspect, which seems to be the actual video address by redirect.
So far, it works well.

Here comes the problem. After I set `video.currentTime`(for seek) for a few times, `C` shows up with [media error code 2](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/video.html#dom-mediaerror-media_err_network). I tried to fetch `A`, `B`, `C` directly, they both work and get the same video.

I don't know how it happends, maybe some kind of cdn policy. Any idea or solution?

Update:
The problem above is on Chrome. I tried Safari, it shows only `A` in element and network inspect, and everything fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in Chrome(ver 51, in Windows 7 and OSX 10.11) and Safari(OSX 10.11). It seems to be a bug in Chrome(OSX 10.11). In Windows 7, `B`, `C`, `D`... are existed and work fine.